# Execution time not precise

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, delay, execution

I am building a **Pov Display** using Raspberry pi 4 and a code written in Go.
The raspberry pi has a **sensor (btn)** to know when it displays the code. The problem is my raspberry won't execute the code  at same delay every detection of (btn), therefore I see dots and some time lines.
**I want just to make the raspberry pi display the code written in Go with same delay every detection** to see just dots.

[image]

```golang
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "time"

    "gobot.io/x/gobot"
    "gobot.io/x/gobot/drivers/gpio"
    "gobot.io/x/gobot/drivers/spi"
    "gobot.io/x/gobot/platforms/raspi"
)

func main() {
    raspberry := raspi.NewAdaptor()

    ledon := spi.NewAPA102Driver(raspberry, 64, 31)
    ledon.WithSpeed(12 * 1000 * 1000)
    ledoff := spi.NewAPA102Driver(raspberry, 64, 31)
    ledoff.WithSpeed(12 * 1000 * 1000)

    for i := 0; i < 64; i++ {
        ledon.SetRGBA(i, color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0x00, B: 0x00, A: 10})
        ledoff.SetRGBA(i, color.RGBA{R: 0x00, G: 0x00, B: 0x00, A: 10})
    }

    btn := gpio.NewButtonDriver(raspberry, "10", time.Microsecond)
    work := func() {
        btn.On(gpio.ButtonPush, func(s interface{}) {
            ledon.Draw()
            ledoff.Draw()
        })
    }

    robot := gobot.NewRobot("ButtonBot",
        []gobot.Connection{raspberry},
        []gobot.Device{ledon, ledoff, btn},
        work)

    robot.Start()
}
```

**NOTE**: As electronic engineer I can tell you that my sensor and electronic system are stable. Besides, I tested an other code with JavaScript and it works fine (same delay every detection) but the display is flickering due softwere problem probably the same in Go.

Comment: For a general-purpose computer like the Pi, because of other processes that run on the CPU, timing in a loop is not always consistent. This is because your code may get interrupted by other processes. Have you tried using an interrupt? I've never tried go on the Pi so I don't know how to do it but if you want stable timing on a microprocessor instead of a microcontroller you should use interrupts

Comment: ... ironically something like this is much easier to do on a cheap microcontroller like an Arduino because you don't have an OS and other processes to mess with your timing

Comment: How does the JavaScript delay compare with the range of Go delays?  And how often do you see the long delay?  And do you know what amount of time that "long" delay represents?

Comment: The test is about display pixel repeatedly , JS is start at detection but flickering , GO some times start in other position just after detection point ( it seems delayed) , flickering and take much time than usual . I see long delayed about once per 3 sec or 5-7 sec sometimes ,  the dots displayed for ~ 320 us then the "long" delay  takes about 3 ms (approximate calculation )

Comment: As @slebetman mentions, any precise sub-millisecond timing cannot be guaranteed on a pi due to the overhead of an OS.

Comment: @TeejayBruno is there any solution to tell the processor to execute my code with priority or an hardware interruption  impose the pi to consternate  on my code ?

Comment: you definitely can try but it will likely result in modifying your kernel -- libraries like http://wiringpi.com/ or http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/ should get you on the right track

Comment: As I mentioned. Interrupts definitely would work. Only I don't know how to do it in go. There are plenty of examples in C/C++ which you can compile as a node module. People have controlled servos with the Pi with rock-solid stability in the output signal so definitely doable.